# Django NameError: name 'bPath' is not defined

Tags: django, django-models

I'm running on Django 1.7 and when I run python manage.py migrate I get the following error

```
      File "/home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/jantiyes.com/src/deeds/migrations/0006_auto_20141204_1631.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
  File "/home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/jantiyes.com/src/deeds/migrations/0006_auto_20141204_1631.py", line 19, in Migration
    field=models.ImageField(storage=django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage(location=bPath('/home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/jantiyes.com/src/media')), max_length=255, null=True, upload_to=deeds.models.picture_name, blank=True),
NameError: name 'bPath' is not defined
```

## This is my deeds/models.py

```
from jantiyes.settings.base import MEDIA_ROOT

upload_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=MEDIA_ROOT)

def picture_name(self, filename):

    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    deedname = re.sub('[ ]', '-', self.text.lower())
    filename = "DEED-%s-%s.%s" % (self.id, deedname, ext)

    url = "%s" % filename

    return url


class Deed(TimeStampedModel):

    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=picture_name, null=True, blank=True, storage=upload_storage, max_length=255)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    when = models.DateField(unique=True)
```

My Media declaration:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(3)
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR.child("media")
```

Comment: Which library is `Path` from? I doesn't look like it's `pathlib` since it doesn't have an `ancestor` method.

Comment: I'm new to Django so not really sure what you want me to check

Comment: For the record I wanted to know from which module your import `Path` from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to tell without the exact definition of `jantiyes.settings.base.MEDIA_ROOT` but I guess it's an instance of a class (`bPath`) that is not [*deconstructible*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#custom-deconstruct-method) and that is a [subclass of `unicode`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4fb38b73073dcd54f4af41a2af14dbc36f5d9f33/django/db/migrations/writer.py#L319-L330). Hence the migration writer assumes it doesn't need any imports and simply `repr` the value which turns out to be `bPath('/home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/jantiyes.com/src/media')`.

You have two options:

1. Make sure `jantiyes.settings.base.MEDIA_ROOT` is defined as string and thus correctly handled by the migration writer. e.g. `MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/jantiyes.com/src/media'` in your `jantiyes.settings.base` module file.
2. Make sure the `bPath` class is *deconstructible* by defining a `deconstruct` method returning the import path to itself.

Comment: my media declaration path. BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(3)
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR.child("media")

Comment: Again, it's hard to tell without the details about the origin of the `Path` class but I'd guess `MEDIA_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.child("media"))` should do?

Comment: str(BASE_DIR.child("media")) fix everything...Bravo

Comment: from the error it doesn't sound like anything to do with deconstructibility... it looks more like migration tries to import a helper function `bPath` which perhaps no longer exists in the project

Comment: @Anentropic the `0006_auto_20141204_1631.py` file was automatically generated by Django's migration framework. I pretty sure my answer is right but no one can tell for sure unless @Yannick provides the name of the third-party package `Path` is imported from.

Comment: it doesn't matter that the migration was auto-generated, the error message and traceback are pretty clear `bPath` is a function which hasn't been imported/doesn't exist `NameError: name 'bPath' is not defined`

Comment: `name 'bPath' is not defined` because it was not automatically imported when the migration was generated. Did you take the time to learn how the migration framework deconstruct an application state to generate those files?

Comment: I have the same issue using fs_private_folder = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.PRIVATE_FOLDER_ROOT) and models.FileField('file', storage=fs_private_folder, upload_to=get_upload_path_message_file). Could you tell me what it is wrong?

Comment: What about `fs_private_folder = FileSystemStorage(location=str(settings.PRIVATE_FOLDER_ROOT))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Where is `MEDIA_ROOT` defined? I'm assuming it's defined in your settings file, in which case you likely need

```
from django.conf import settings

upload_storage = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Yes I have from jantiyes.settings.base import MEDIA_ROOT

Comment: My guess then is that it doesn't like `upload_storage` is defined outside of an `__init__` function. Code inside of an `__init__` function only gets called at instantiation, but code outside of it gets called whenever you run `migrate` or `runserver`.